# Imported Python file runs without any code in body or any main function. How can I manipulate this file?

Tags: python, import

Here's my code showing the imported file. The imported file runs once. As you can see, it runs without any code - even a main function.

```py
import PYTHON_FILE

def main():
   while True:
       with open .PYTHON_FILE as f:
       f.flush()
main()
```

Runs the same as `import PYTHON_FILE` all by itself.

I import PYTHON_FILE into CURRENT_FILE and it runs no matter what code I put into the body of CURRENT_FILE. However, I want to flush the memory values from the first execution so that PYTHON_FILE has blank variable values and another execution of PYTHON_FILE will not cause an error.

Comment: I'm not clear on the issue, but the imported file only runs once even if you import it multiple times. As for variables, try creating a class in the imported file so the variables don't get initialized when the file is imported.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is that the imported file runs regardless of any code in my current file. The imported simple executes no matter what code I put in. I literally just type, "import PYTHON_FILE" and nothing else and the imported file just runs automatically. Yes, I definitely need to start using classes and utilize the power of OOP.

Comment: The import statement can be anywhere is your code. You can also conditionally import a file: `if x==1: import PYTHON_FILE`